# $b$-metric induced topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

We know that:

‎A b-metric $d$ on a  nonempty set $X$ is a function $d:X \times X \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ which satisfies the following conditions for all $x,y,z\in X$‎:
‎
‎$d(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=y‎$‎ ,

‎ $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$‎ ,

‎$d(x,y)\leq s[d(x,z)+d(z,y)]$ ($b$-triangular inequality)‎,

‎where $s\in[1,\infty)$‎. 
‎Then‎, ‎the pair $(X,d)$ is called a $b$-metric space with parameter $s$.
Let ‎‎$$\mathcal{B}‎‎=\{B(x,‎\varepsilon)|‎\varepsilon >0 , x\in X \}‎‎,$$
where
$$B(x,‎\varepsilon)=\{y\in X |d(x,y)<‎\varepsilon\}.$$‎‎
1)Prove that $B$ is a base for $X$.

2)How we define a topology on a b-metric space.

Comment: You must have got your answer by now. Nevertheless, to answer your question 2, consider $\mathcal{B_1}$ to be the collection of all finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{B}$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not necessary. Consider a following counterexample. Let $$X=S\cup \{x_1\}\cup\{x_2\},$$ where $$S=\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n\in\Bbb N\}\subset [0,1]$$ is a convergent sequence, and $d(x,y)$ equals $|x-y|$, if both $x$ and $y$ are in $S$, $$d(0,x_1)=d(x_1,0)=d(0,x_2)=d(x_2,0)=1,$$
$$d(x,x_1)=d(x_1,x)=d(x,x_2)=d(x_2,x)=2$$ for each $x\in S\setminus\{0\},$ 
and $$d(x_1,x_2)=d(x_2,x_1)=2.$$

Then $d$ is a $b$-metric on $X$ with parameter $2$. Indeed, let $x,y,z$  be arbitrary points of $X$. If some two among $x,y,z$ coincide then $b$-triangle inequality easily follows. Otherwise, if one among $x,y,z$ is $x_1$ or $x_2$ then $d(x,y)\le 2\le 2[d(x,z)+d(z,y)]$. Otherwise, all of $x,y,z$ belong to $S$, and $b$-triangle inequality $d(x,y)\le 2\le 2[d(x,z)+d(z,y)]$ follows from the triangle inequality
$d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$ for $S$. Finally, an intersection $B(x_1,3/2)\cap B(x_2,3/2)$ equals to 
$\{0\}$ and contains no elements of $\mathcal B$, a contradiction.